# Uninitialized variables in program to convert polar to cartesian and vice-versa(C)

Tags: c, floating-point, function-prototypes

So our program is to convert cartesian coordinates x,y to polar coordinates r,theta using prototype functions place AFTER the main function with outputting done from within the main. My program looks like this after some TA help, but the compiler is telling me that my prototypes aren't initialized.
Here's my code:

```
//
//ESE 124 Homework 8

#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

float cartesianToPolar1(float x, float y);

float cartesianToPolar2(float x, float y);

float polarToCartesian1(float r);

float polarToCartesian2(float theta);

int main(){
    int runmode;
    float x, y, r, theta;
    float cartesianToPolar1, cartesianToPolar2, polarToCartesian1,      polarToCartesian2;
    while(1){
        printf("Please enter a value of 1 or 2 for runmode:   ");
        scanf_s("%d", &runmode);

    switch(runmode){

    case 1:

        printf("Please enter in the keyboard a value for 'x':   ");
        scanf_s("%f", &x);

        printf("Please enter in the keyboard a value for 'y':   ");
        scanf_s("%f", &y);

        r=cartesianToPolar1;
        theta=cartesianToPolar2;

        printf("\nx=%.2f\ty=%.2f\tr=%.2f\ttheta=%.2f\n", x,y,r,theta);
        break;

    case 2: 

       printf("Please enter in the keyboard a value for 'r':   ");
       scanf_s("%f", &r);

       printf("Please enter in the keyboard a value for 'theta':   ");
       scanf_s("%f", &theta);

       x=polarToCartesian1;
       y=polarToCartesian2;

       printf("\nr=%.2f\ttheta=%.2f\tx=%.2f\ty=%.2f\n", r,theta,x,y);
       break;

    default: 

       printf("\nUnallowed value of runmode, Please re-enter a value of 1 or 2.\n");
    }
    }
return 0;
}

float cartesianToPolar1(float x, float y, float r){
    float cartesianToPolar1=r;
        r=sqrt(x*x+y*y);
        return cartesianToPolar1;
}

float cartesianToPolar2(float y, float x, float s, float theta){
    float cartesianToPolar2=theta;
        s=y/x;
        theta=atan(s);
    return cartesianToPolar2;
}

float polarToCartesian1(float theta, float r, float x){
    float polarToCartesian1=x;
        x=r*cos(theta); 
    return polarToCartesian1;
}

float polarToCartesian2(float theta, float r, float y){
    float polarToCartesian2=y;
        y=r*sin(theta);
    return polarToCartesian2;
}
```

I have tried declaring them to 0 and 1, but nothing has worked thus far. As for the actual code, I have it exactly the way the professor wants it according to the TA, just missing that last step. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Giving your ID number along with full name here is not a best idea..

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: As well as the function prototypes not matching their implementation, they attempt to return the function itself, instead of the calculated value.

Comment: Also, in `main` you have declared `float` variables with names that match the functions, this is a very poor practice. You go on to use these uninitialised variables as if they were the results of the functions of the same name.

Comment: I'm sure you can tell I'm new to programming. My professor is not a very good one so a lot of the time I am forced to do things by myself with literally (and I mean that) no background. We covered prototype functions for 5 minutes in class, then he proceeded to do some examples, none of which involved the technique we were supposed to use in this assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The prototype function signature must match the actual function implementation. Which is not the case with your code.

Comment: This is a problem, but it is not the immediately critical problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous faults in the code, which I have commented in the code below. Summarised they are:

- Function prototypes do not match the function implementation.
- Functions' local variables presented as function arguments.
- Function arguments defined in the wrong sequence.
- Trying the return the function name as its value.
- Possible divide by 0 error in the `atan(y/x)` calculation.
- Having variables in `main` which duplicate the function names.

Finally I would change the use of `float` to `double` throughout (with corresponding changes to `scanf` format specifier). The math library functions work with `double` and warnings are generated about this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

float cartesianToPolar1(float x, float y);
float cartesianToPolar2(float x, float y);
float polarToCartesian1(float r, float theta);
float polarToCartesian2(float r, float theta);

int main(void){
    int runmode;
    float x, y, r, theta;
    while(1){
        printf("Please enter a value of 1 or 2 for runmode:   ");
        scanf_s("%d", &runmode);

    switch(runmode){
        case 1:
            printf("Please enter in the keyboard a value for 'x':   ");
            scanf_s("%f", &x);

            printf("Please enter in the keyboard a value for 'y':   ");
            scanf_s("%f", &y);

            r=cartesianToPolar1(x, y);          // <--- pass arguments
            theta=cartesianToPolar2(x, y);      // <--- pass arguments

            printf("\nx=%.2f\ty=%.2f\tr=%.2f\ttheta=%.2f\n", x,y,r,theta);
            break;

        case 2: 
           printf("Please enter in the keyboard a value for 'r':   ");
           scanf_s("%f", &r);

           printf("Please enter in the keyboard a value for 'theta':   ");
           scanf_s("%f", &theta);

           x=polarToCartesian1(r, theta);       // <--- pass arguments
           y=polarToCartesian2(r, theta);       // <--- pass arguments

           printf("\nr=%.2f\ttheta=%.2f\tx=%.2f\ty=%.2f\n", r,theta,x,y);
           break;

        default: 
           printf("\nUnallowed value of runmode, Please re-enter a value of 1 or 2.\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

float cartesianToPolar1(float x, float y){      // <--- remove unnecessary arguments
    float r;                                    // <--- correct variable
    r=sqrt(x*x+y*y);
    return r;                                   // <--- return calculated value
}

float cartesianToPolar2(float x, float y){      // <--- swapped reversed arguments too
    float theta;                                // <--- correct variable
    //s=y/x;                                    // <--- avoid divide by zero potential
    theta=atan2(y, x);
    return theta;                               // <--- return calculated value
}

float polarToCartesian1(float r, float theta){  // <--- swapped reversed arguments too
    float x;                                    // <--- correct variable
    x=r*cos(theta); 
    return x;                                   // <--- return calculated value
}

float polarToCartesian2(float r, float theta){  // <--- swapped reversed arguments too
    float y;                                    // <--- correct variable
    y=r*sin(theta);
    return y;                                   // <--- return calculated value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float cartesianToPolar1(float x, float y){
    float r;
    r=sqrt(x*x+y*y);
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have hidden your functions by (uninitialized) local variables.  This leads to confusion.

You have:

```
float cartesianToPolar1(float x, float y);
float cartesianToPolar2(float x, float y);
float polarToCartesian1(float r);
float polarToCartesian2(float theta);

int main(){
    int runmode;
    float x, y, r, theta;
    // This next line is a major cause of confusion!
    float cartesianToPolar1, cartesianToPolar2, polarToCartesian1, polarToCartesian2;
    while(1){
        …
        r=cartesianToPolar1;       // Cannot write cartesianToPolar1(x, y) here
        theta=cartesianToPolar2;   // Cannot write cartesianToPolars2(x, y) here
```

The local variables mean that the `main()` can no longer call the functions.  Some compilers can generate warnings when you hide a global object with a local object of the same name.  With GCC, you'd use `-Wshadow` to get the information.

You need:

```
float cartesianToPolar1(float x, float y);
float cartesianToPolar2(float x, float y);
float polarToCartesian1(float r);
float polarToCartesian2(float theta);

int main(){
    int runmode;
    float x, y, r, theta;
    // removed
    while(1){
        …
        r = cartesianToPolar1(x, y);
        theta = cartesianToPolar2(x, y);
```

You will also have problems with the `polarToCartesian[12]()` functions; you need to pass both `r` and `theta` to both functions — so they can return `x` or `y`.

You could also improve the function names:

```
  float cartesianToPolarTheta(float x, float y);
  float cartesianToPolarRadius(float x, float y);

  float polarToCartesianX(float r, float theta);
  float polarToCartesianY(float r, float theta);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It actually makes sense now!